# R fit user defined distribution

Tags: r, distribution, fitdistrplus

I am trying to fit my own distribution to my data, find the optimum parameters of the distribution to match the data and ultimately find the FWHM of the peak in the distribution. From what I've read, the package fitdistrplus is the way to do this. I know the data takes the shape of a lorentzian peak on a quadratic background.

plot of the data:
[plot of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gB1y.png)

The raw data used:

```
data = c(0,2,5,4,5,4,3,3,2,2,0,4,4,2,5,5,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,5,5,6,6,8,4,0,6,5,7,5,6,3,2,1,7,0,7,9,5,7,5,3,5,5,4,1,4,8,10,2,5,8,7,14,7,5,8,4,2,2,6,5,4,6,5,7,5,4,8,5,4,8,11,9,4,8,11,7,8,6,9,5,8,9,10,8,4,5,8,10,9,12,10,10,5,5,9,9,11,19,17,9,17,10,17,18,11,14,15,12,11,14,12,10,10,8,7,13,14,17,18,16,13,16,14,17,20,15,12,15,16,18,24,23,20,17,21,20,20,23,20,15,20,28,27,26,20,17,19,27,21,28,32,29,20,19,24,19,19,22,27,28,23,37,41,42,34,37,29,28,28,27,38,32,37,33,23,29,55,51,41,50,44,46,53,63,49,50,47,54,54,43,45,58,54,55,67,52,57,67,69,62,62,65,56,72,75,88,87,77,70,71,84,85,81,84,75,78,80,82,107,102,98,82,93,98,90,94,118,107,113,103,99,103,96,108,114,136,126,126,124,130,126,113,120,107,107,106,107,136,143,135,151,132,117,118,108,120,145,140,122,135,153,157,133,130,128,109,106,122,133,132,150,156,158,150,137,147,150,146,144,144,149,171,185,200,194,204,211,229,225,235,228,246,249,238,214,228,250,275,311,323,327,341,368,381,395,449,474,505,529,585,638,720,794,896,919,1008,1053,1156,1134,1174,1191,1202,1178,1236,1200,1130,1094,1081,1009,949,890,810,760,690,631,592,561,515,501,489,467,439,388,377,348,345,310,298,279,253,257,259,247,237,223,227,217,210,213,197,197,192,195,198,201,202,211,193,203,198,202,174,164,162,173,170,184,170,168,175,170,170,168,162,149,139,145,151,144,152,155,170,156,149,147,158,171,163,146,151,150,147,137,123,127,136,149,147,124,137,133,129,130,128,139,137,147,141,123,112,136,147,126,117,116,100,110,120,105,91,100,100,105,92,88,78,95,75,75,82,82,80,83,83,66,73,80,76,69,81,93,79,71,80,90,72,72,63,57,53,62,65,49,51,57,73,54,56,78,65,52,58,49,47,56,46,43,50,43,40,39,36,45,28,35,36,43,48,37,36,35,39,31,24,29,37,26,22,36,33,24,31,31,20,30,28,23,21,27,26,29,21,20,22,18,19,19,20,21,20,25,18,12,18,20,20,13,14,21,20,16,18,12,17,20,24,21,20,18,11,17,12,5,11,13,16,13,13,12,12,9,15,13,15,11,12,11,8,13,16,16,16,14,8,8,10,11,11,17,15,15,9,9,13,12,3,11,14,11,14,13,8,7,7,15,12,8,12,14,9,5,2,10,8)
```

I have calculated the equations which define the distribution and cumulative distribution:

```
dFF <- function(x,a,b,c,A,gamma,pos) a + b*x + (c*x^2) + ((A/pi)*(gamma/(((x-pos)^2) + (gamma^2))))

pFF <- function(x,a,b,c,A,gamma,pos) a*x + (b/2)*(x^2) + (c/3)*(x^3) + A/2 + (A/pi)*(atan((x - pos)/gamma))
```

I believe these to be correct. From what I understand, a distribution fit should be possible using just these definitions using the fitdist (or mledist) method:

```
fitdist(data,'FF', start = list(0,0.3,-0.0004,70000,13,331))
mledist(data,'FF', start = list(0,0.3,-0.0004,70000,13,331))
```

This returns the statement *'function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters> Error in fitdist(data, "FF", start = list(0, 0.3, -4e-04, 70000, 13, 331)):the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100'* in the first case and in the second I just get a list of 'NA' values for the estimates.

I then calculated a function to give the quantile distribution values to use the other fitting methods (qmefit):

```
qFF <- function(p,a,b,c,A,gamma,pos)
{
     qList = c()
     axis = seq(1,600,1)
     aF = dFF(axis,a,b,c,A,gamma,pos)
     arr = histogramCpp(aF) # change data to a histogram format
     for(element in 1:length(p)){
         q = quantile(arr,p[element], names=FALSE)
         qList = c(qList,q)
     }
     return(qList)
}
```

Part of this code requires calling the c++ function (by using the library Rcpp):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int>  histogramCpp(NumericVector x) {
    std::vector<int> arr;
    double number, fractpart, intpart;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 600; i++){
        number = (x[i]);
        fractpart = modf(number , &intpart);
        if(fractpart < 0.5){
            number = (int) intpart;
        }
        if(fractpart >= 0.5){
            number = (int) (intpart+1);
        }
        for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++){
            arr.push_back(i);
        }
   }
   return arr;
}
```

This c++ method just turns the data into a histogram format. If the first element of the vector describing the data is 4 then '1' is added 4 times to the returned vector etc. . This also seems to work as sensible values are returned. plot of the quantile function:

[Plot of quantiles returned for probabilities from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dnip.png)

The 'qmefit' method can then be attempted through the fitdist function:

```
fitdist(data,'FF', start = list(0,0.3,-0.0004,70000,13,331), method = 'qme', probs = c(0,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9))
```

I chose the 'probs' values randomly as I don't fully understand their meaning. This either straight-up crashes the R session or after a brief stuttering returns a list of 'NA' values as estimates and the line    `<std::bad_alloc : std::bad_alloc>`

I am not sure if I am making a basic mistake here and any help or recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to find a work-around for this using the rPython package and lmfit from python. It solved my issue and might be useful for others with the same issue. The R-code was as follows:

```
library(rPython)
python.load("pyFit.py")
python.assign("row",pos)
python.assign("vals",vals)
python.exec("FWHM,ERROR,FIT = fitDist(row,vals)")
FWHM = python.get("FWHM")
ERROR = python.get("ERROR")
cFIT = python.get("FIT")
```

and the called python code was:

```
from lmfit import  Model, minimize, Parameters, fit_report
from sklearn import mixture
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def cauchyDist(x,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,A,gamma,pos):
    return  a + b*x + c*pow(x,2) + d*pow(x,3) + e*pow(x,4) + f*pow(x,5) + g*pow(x,6) + (A/np.pi)*(gamma/((pow((x-pos),2)) + (pow(gamma,2))))

def fitDist(row, vals):  
    gmod = Model(cauchyDist)

    x = np.arange(0,600)
    result = gmod.fit(vals, x=x, a = 0, b = 0.3, c = -0.0004, d = 0, e = 0, f= 0, g = 0, A = 70000, gamma = 13, pos = row)

    newFile = open('fitData.txt', 'w')
    newFile.write(result.fit_report())
    newFile.close()

    with open('fitData.txt', 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF: 
            if 'gamma:' in line:
                j = line.split()
    inF.close()

    FWHM = float(j[1])
    error = float(j[3])
    fit = result.best_fit
    fit  = fit.tolist()
    return FWHM, error, fit
```

I increased the order of polynomial to obtain a better fit for the data and returned the FWHM, its error and the values for the fit. There are likely much better ways of achieving this but the final fit is as I needed.

[Final fit. Red data points are raw data, the black line is the fitted distribution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Liev.png)